# Debugging python async race condition with defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write something that collates a set of inputs that are sent within some time frame into a single request. My code is similar to:

```py
in_dict = defaultdict(list)
out_dict = defaultdict(list)
guard = asyncio.Lock()

async def collate(k, v):
    async with guard:
        in_dict[k].append(v)
    await asyncio.sleep(wait_time)
    async with guard:
        if k in in_dict and in_dict[k]:
            out_dict[k] = out_dict[k] + in_dict.pop(k)
        elif k in out_dict:
            handle_collated(out_dict.pop(k))
```

However, there seems to be a race condition somewhere where `out_dict[k]` still contains elements that have been processed.

Thanks

Comment: Read about [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

`...out_dict[k] still contains elements that have been processed.` - It isn't clear what the intent is from your example so a solution won't be possible. On the surface it looks like a logic problem.

Leaving the async aside:

```
>>> in_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> out_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

The code  always *makes* a `k:v` item in `in_dict` first

```
>>> k, v = 1, ''
>>> in_dict[k].append(v)
```

So `if k in in_dict and in_dict[k]` will always be `True` and the `elif` suite will never be executed.

```
>>> k in in_dict
True
>>> bool(in_dict[k])
True
>>>
>>> if k in in_dict and in_dict[k]:
...     out_dict[k] = out_dict[k] + in_dict.pop(k)
... elif k in out_dict:
...     print(f'elif executed: {out_dict.pop(k)}')

>>> in_dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})
>>> out_dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['']})
```

Next *call*

```
>>> k,v = 1,'q'
>>> in_dict[k].append(v)
>>>
>>> if k in in_dict and in_dict[k]:
...     out_dict[k] = out_dict[k] + in_dict.pop(k)
... elif k in out_dict:
...     print(f'elif executed: {out_dict.pop(k)}')
>>>
>>> in_dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})
>>> out_dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['', 'q']})
>>>
```

---

[The `if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement)

Comment: Sorry, bad copy paste! Should have been in_dict.pop(k). Amended the post. Thanks for the taking the time though, my bad.

Comment: @cosplay-raven - updated: regardless, the `elif` suite never gets executed.